# How to fix "(private method `registration_confirmation' called for UserMailer:Class) " rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, email-verification

I'm new to ruby on rails and trying to add email verification to my server when a user registers. I am following a 2017 guide for rails 4 here https://coderwall.com/p/u56rra/ruby-on-rails-user-signup-email-confirmation-tutorial . and i am getting this error, "NoMethodError (private method `registration_confirmation' called for UserMailer:Class):
"

This is something new i'd like to add to my server to enforce email verification, i recently had a welcome mail sent out to new users when they sign up, and i am working on adding the verification email however this is not working and keeps throwing me an error. I suppose the guide i am following is old and so i make some changes to the code to make it more similar like the welcome email sent out.

this is the user mailer code for welcome:

```
   class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base 
   default from: 'hello@thecitizenshub.com' 

   def welcome_email 
      @user = params[:user] 
      @url = 'https://thecitizenshub.com/login' 
      mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome') 
   end 
 end 

   def registration_confirmation 
     @user = params[:user] 
     mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Registration Confirmation') 
   end
```

this is the user mailer code for Registration confirmation:

```
def registration_confirmation
  @user = params[:user]
  mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Registration Confirmation')
end
```

code for user controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome email after save
      UserMailer.with(user: @user).welcome_email.deliver_later
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      render json: @user, status: :created
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

i expect that when someone signs up, they should get the verification email, but this error keeps coming up and so i keep getting `There was an error processing your request..` and in the console it gives `NoMethodError (private method`registration_confirmation' called for UserMailer:Class):
` when testing signup i'm using rails Rails 5.2.2
 if that helps

Comment: Welcome aboard, Clement! Can you post add more context around the error message? That context would include the error lines before you see `NoMethodError (private method `registration_confirmation' called for UserMailer:Class` Also, could you post the entire `user_mailer.rb` file in the question above? You can edit your question and add those changes.

Comment: I suppose, there is a `private` line in the UserMailer class, above `registration_confirmation` method? In rails, all methods below it become private, and you can't call them outside. To solve the problem, move all private methods to the end of the file, or remove `private` if you don't need it

Comment: Hi Clement, Welcome to rails. I wrote the tutorial and can confirm what Vasilisa mentioned in their comment here. As I mentioned on Twitter I would recommend using Devise for this functionality however if you want to resolve your issue please make sure the method exists as a public method. If you have the word `private` anywhere in your UserMailer file, remove it and try again (for an example of what I'm to remove see the line above `def confirmation_token` in the tutorial).

Comment: i posted the complete code in the user mail, sharing once again ```# app/mailers/ApplicationMailer.rb
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'hello@thecitizenshub.com'

  def welcome_email
    @user = params[:user]
    @url  = 'https://thecitizenshub.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome')
  end
end


def registration_confirmation
  @user = params[:user]
  mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Registration Confirmation')
end
```
@Vasilisa

Comment: @Clement, you placed exta `end` after `welcome_email`, it closes UserMailer class. Move it to the end of file